# php: how to include a php file properly for built-in local webserver?

Tags: php, html

I'm using php for the first time. I've been developing an application using the php built-in webserver on my windows machine https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php . My site exists at localhost:8000.

This is the code I have for my `index.html` homepage. It's just supposed to be a simple html with the `<head>` and `<body>` tags with needed scripts. This application is an online experiment. A javascript framework is used in the file expchatbot.js that includes all the text/visual stuff to render.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="resources/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <script src="libraries/jspsych-6.1.0/jspsych.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/expchatbot.js"></script>
    <?php
    include 'assignSubjectCondition.php';
    ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Meanwhile, this is the code I have for my php file `assignSubjectCondition.php` . It's just meant to read all the csvs that exist in `server_root/data`, or a folder called `data/` that exists in the server root. I'm just confused at the result because... right now, the php echo statements get rendered to the html page (which I expect... albeit, I actually just want these statements to print to terminal). But then, the remaining html code that's actually inside of/generated by expchatbot.js is also rendered on the page and unstyled.

I'm not sure if this is right, but I get the server to run my php script by using the command `php -S localhost:8000  assignSubjectCondition.php`

```
<?php
$dir    = 'data/';
$csvFiles = glob($dir . '*csv');

foreach($csvFiles as $f) {
  echo "current csv file: " . $f;
  $row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($f, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $csv[] = $data;
        echo $csv[1][8];
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
}
?>
```

[image]

What's going on here with the rendering? I've found examples where people weren't the `<?php ?>` opening and closing statements but I have those here so... It seems like php is rendering all the code now for some reason.

The point of this php script is literally to grab any row and read what is in column 8 of that row. I just need to do that once for each csv. I'm not sure if the error is actually related to how this is currently written (it was put together based on some answers I saw on stackoverflow).  I don't need the portion that iterates through columns (the for loop) but I included it particularly because I'm confused at why including this line results in the contents of my expchatbot.js file getting rendered.

A follow up question I have is, what actually is `$csv[] = data;` doing? I haven't been able to figure that out either, other than that it seemingly reads data from an array.

Comment: why are you including it in the <head> of the doc and not <body>?

Comment: *I actually just want these statements to print to terminal* php is not like nodejs, when you do `echo` it outputs to the browser. you won't get anything rendered to the terminal because the inbuilt server is like running it through a webserver not CLI

Answer (score 1):

The line `$csv[] = $data;` append the current row read from the csv file (which is an array) to another array named `$csv`. The $csv variable is initialized with this assignment. In the context of the snippet, you provided it is similar to this:

```
$csv = [0 => $data];
```

The errors comes from the line `echo $csv[1][8];`. This line is trying to access the 9th item (arrays in PHP start at 0) of the 2nd item of the $csv variable. It is akin to this code:

```
$secondItemOfCsv = $csv[1]
$ninthItemOfSeconItemOfRow = $secondItemOfCsv[8]
```

`$csv[1]` tries to access the second item of `$csv` but it does not exist therefore PHP notify you via a Notice that there might be an error but continue its execution assigning null to `$secondItemOfCsv`

`$secondItemOfCsv` is `null` whence the impossibility of accessing its 9th item therefore PHP notify you via a Notice that there might be an error but continue its execution.

Aside from this, from the description you have given, the `include` should not be between `<head></head>`. The `<head>` element is a container for metadata (data about data). Refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) link for more information. The include should be below inside the `<body>` element.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize fgetscsv was allowing me to iterate row by row in the csv file. that indexing warning  makes sense. Also the php include into the `<body>` element... But I'm still getting weird rendering behavior. I'm still seeing my expchatbot.js stuff being unstylized and rendered on the page. Also what's weird to me is that if I comment out all `echo` statements then try to go to localhost:8000, all I get is a blank web page. Why is php seeming to override any other content on the page?

Comment: also as a follow up question... Why does `echo $csv[0][8];` return me "condition", the header at column 8... but `echo $data[8]` returns me an actual entry from the "condition" column rather than just the header string?